# fullcalendar: how can i get the first and last day of the relevant viewed month (and not the days of of the prev \ next month)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, ajax, fullcalendar

i want to know what is the first day and the last day of the main month viewed in fullcalendar.

here is the relevant month view:

[image]

```
     events: function (start, end, timezone, callback) { //custom events function to be called every time the view changes
          alert (start.format());
          alert (end.format());
     },
```

when i run this code on this month (april 2017), i get:
start.format()=2017-03-26 
end.format()= 2017-05-07
and i would like to get the following dates:
start: 2017-04-01
end:  2017-04-30

is there any way for me to get this dates inside the event function?

many thanks

p.s

i would not like to use the "showNonCurrentDates: false" option

Comment: With release of `v4`, it is much easier. `<viewObject>.currentStart()` and `<viewObject>.currentEnd()`. For example, `datesRender: function(info) { console.log(info.view.currentStart.format("YYYY-MM-DD")); console.log(info.view.currentEnd.format("YYYY-MM-DD")); }`

Comment: @Fr0zenFyr You are awesome, solved my problem and saved my life. I was searching this solution for 1 hour. Thanks dear.

Comment: Glad it helped you @Kamlesh. Cheers!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There's no direct way to get this value via the "events" callback, but you can use a slightly kludgy workaround:

The viewRender callback gives you access to the "view" object of the current view, which contains the `intervalStart` and `intervalEnd` properties (see https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v3/view-object) which relate to the interval the view is trying to represent. In a month view, this will be the start and end of the month. If you capture these into variables with a higher scope than your calendar, you can then re-use them in the events and/or eventsAfterAllRender callbacks, as needed.

```
var intervalStart, intervalEnd; //variables with higher scope level

$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
   //...your options here...
    viewRender: function (view, element)
    {
        intervalStart = view.intervalStart;
        intervalEnd = view.intervalEnd;
    },
    events: function(start, end, timezone, callback) {
        console.log(intervalStart.format("YYYY-MM-DD"));
        console.log(intervalEnd.format("YYYY-MM-DD"));
        //...etc
    }
});
```

Note that `intervalEnd` is **exclusive**, so if the month is April, the `intervalEnd` will be given as 1st May.

Having demonstrated that though, it seems neater just to use the built-in `showNonCurrentDates:false` option, as in your earlier question.

Comment: Thanks again. did u build the fullcalendar? :)

Comment: Nope. I just use it quite a bit, and I'm familiar with the documentation. This guy wrote it, I believe. http://stackoverflow.com/users/96342/arshaw but it doesn't look like he's all that active on here recently.

Comment: p.s: this view.intervalEnd returns the first day of the next month (i.e  2017-05-01). to get the last day of the month use (i.e  2017-04-30) intervalEnd = view.intervalEnd.subtract(1, 'days');

Comment: yes I know - that's what I meant when I said the intervalEnd is an exclusive date (as mentioned in the fullCalendar documentation).

Comment: With release of `v4`, it is much easier. `<viewObject>.currentStart()` and `<viewObject>.currentEnd()`. For example, `datesRender: function(info) { console.log(info.view.currentStart.format("YYYY-MM-DD")); console.log(info.view.currentEnd.format("YYYY-MM-DD")); }`

Comment: @Fr0zenFyr how is that easier exactly? It's just the same thing with different syntax as far as I can see. And also `currentStart` and `currentEnd` will be Date objects, not momentJS objects, so I wouldn't expect `.format()` to work on them. It would only be "easier" in the sene you could use `calendar.view` directly in the "events" callback (which is where this questioner wanted to get hold of the values, not in view/datesRender at all) since it's now a property of the calendar.

Answer (score 2):

Add this setting `showNonCurrentDates: false,`. With this setting, dates that do not belong to the current month will not be shown. From you event callbacks the first day of the current month and the first day of the next month will be shown as the `start` and `end` respectively

```
 $('#calendarLoansByRequestDate').fullCalendar({
            // Other settings
            showNonCurrentDates: false,
            events: function (start, end, timezone, callback) { //custom events function to be called every time the view changes
                alert(start.format());
                alert(end.format());
            }
 });
```

Answer (score 2):

I achieved the desired result by using the `activeStart` and `activeEnd` view object properties.

https://fullcalendar.io/docs/view-object